# GCC 5.X integration on Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, gcc

I need to use/integrate GCC 5.X (in my case 5.3, and it is already installed) on Xcode 6.2.

I've found a lot of outdated tutorials about GCC 4.X and Xcode 5 (or lower), but all of them are outdated and do not work anymore.

I've also found [this tutorial](http://hamelot.io/programming/add-gcc-compiler-to-xcode-6/), but I have not the 5.3.xcplugin file that the tuto recommend to copy.

I am still on Mac OS X Maverick, and I can install Xcode 7 if necessary.

Anybody would know how to do it?

Comment: As an aside I can only see wanting gcc for C++ issues if so Xcode is not that good an IDE for C++ and I would look for something else

Comment: @Mark Any recommandation?

Comment: Unfortunately not they all seem to lack something :)  Eclipse is OK its problem is not having the llvm debugger

Comment: Ouch... I was using Eclipse for Java before, and I fed up about it. If it is ok for C++, I may use it, the absence of debugger is ok.

Comment: The debugger will be in Eclipse for gcc it is not there for llvm based code